# can't install 2nd app on one site with ISS7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I am hosting an asp.net application on an IIS 7.5 server. The url is www.foobar.com/, it is mapped to foobar/current.

I am now trying to add a bug tracking system (bugtracker.net) which is run as a separate asp.net application. I created a "second level" new app under site foobar and called it btnet. Is mapped to the pysical directory foobarcom/btnet and uses a new asp.net 4.0 app pool

When I now go to www.foobar.com/btnet my reqest is not served by the (second level) btnet app as I expected but by the foobar parent app. (Which of course can't make sense of the path.)

What do I have to do to get the second level app activated? Bonus point: Is there a better bug tracking system that works with sqlserver08/IIS? (Unfortunately, installing mysql or postgres is not an option for me.)

Cheers,
Duffy

Comment: Voting to move to server fault.  This is a server configuration question.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check whether you have mapped the application properly.

Do you think a hosting issue tracking system is good option? It saves you a lot of effort in setting up the server. You can check out [Issue Tracking Anywhere](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/bug-tracking-issue-tracking-anywhere.aspx) to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: The mapping is correct, as far as I can see. However, I noticed that ISS lists the content of the "parent app" foobar directly under the sites tab and the "secondary app" btnet (for www.foobar.com/btnet) on the same level as the foobar content. I would have expected foobar and foobar/btnet to be two parallel apps.